# Ubuntu Lenovo X1 carbon 16.04 trackpad issues

Tags: kernel, touchpad, lenovo

I'm using a Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo X1 carbon 5th gen. I recently updated my kernel to 4.15-0.46 and have not got an issue with my trackpad. When I start the computer, all works fine until I close the lid or suspend the computer. After this however, the click and drag function on the track pad is extremely slow an unresponsive. All other mouse functions like 2 finger scrolling and the trackpointer are completely fine.

My current work around is to simply restart the mouse driver using

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

This is a temporary solution specified [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082577/thinkpad-x1-carbon-5th-gen-2017-touchpad-behaviour-changed-degraded-a-few/1083739#1083739?newreg=7d4cf4f8260b4c8693846606b700c5ae). I was hoping that anyone could point to a more permanent solution. I have not had this issue on any other previous kernel.