# Touchpad not working properly on Lenovo Carbon x1

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad, synaptics

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 on a Lenovo X1 Carbon laptop. Everything works well except the touchpad.

Essentially it works, but when the machine goes into sleep after being idle for a while (like 30 minutes), the touchpad stops working as well. The main problem is that I can't do two finger scrolling (one finger stable the other moving) to select text. When this happens the only way to select text is to move both fingers, which is not very accurrate and uncomfortable.

Secondly, if the computer is sleeping for a longer time (like an hour), the touchpad just straight up breaks and won't respond at all.

Looking around the internet, I see there's a lot of problems with Lenovo's touchpad and Linux. some of the solutions given are very complex and above my technical levels and appear to be work arounds rather than solution. I'm pretty frustrated, because I just bought this computer to be my main work laptop, but It's going to e ridiculous having to restart my computer throughout the day, just to get things done.

Anyone have a solution.

Comment: does this answer your question? [1202561](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202561/restarting-mysterious-touchpad-driver-in-19-10)

Comment: Hi Iggy I think I understand the principle of your answer there. (essentially running a script that would reboot the touchpad), but I'm afraid it's a bit technical for me.

I ran lsmod in the terminal and one of the things that came up was"i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915" is that the thing I'm looking to work with?


If I run "modprobe -r i2c_hid" followed by "modprobe i2c_hid" in terminal might that help reboot the touchpad?

Comment: If I follow what you're saying, I believe the answer is yes, either that, or the `i2c_algo_bit`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [restarting mysterious touchpad driver in 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202561/restarting-mysterious-touchpad-driver-in-19-10)