# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - both touchpad and USB mouse no longer click - have tried various methods that don't work

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad

A few days ago, my touchpad mouse (right and left buttons) on a Toshiba Satellite C650 series and any and all connected USB mice stopped having the ability to control the GUI with clicking. The laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I can still move the mouse, but clicking does not work.

I have tried both of the steps suggested at this Web page (https://sourcedigit.com/21687-ubuntu-usb-mouse-not-working-ubuntu-touchpad-not-working/).

I have tried the following set of commands from this Web page (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49272/restart-usb-mouse-driver):

```
sudo modprobe -r usbhid && sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe usbhid && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

In addition, I have also tried this set of commands from this Web page ([Is there a way to "restart" the touchpad driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528293/is-there-a-way-to-restart-the-touchpad-driver)):

```
sudo modprobe -r synaptics_12c && sudo modprobe synaptics_12c
sudo modprobe -r synaptics_usb && sudo modprobe synaptidcs_usb
```

Lastly, I have also tried the following 2 commands:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Function + F9 (Turn off and Turn on Toshiba touchpad)

Are there any other suggestions to re-enable the touchpad and USB mice (I have tried 2 different USB mice with the same result)?

Thank you.