# Touchpad stopped working after hibernate on Thinkpad X1 Carbon with Ubuntu and Pop!_OS 21.10

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, hibernate, 21.10

Having issues with my Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 9.

When I hibernate **Ubuntu 21.10** (or also *Pop!_OS 21.10* - I've got multiple installations on the system), the touchpad stops working. Both with Wayland and xorg. Kernel on Ubuntu 21.10: 5.13.0-22.22. I'm using Gnome.

I tried reloading the kernel module with:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse; sleep 2; sudo modprobe psmouse
```

I also tried dis-/enabling the xinput device:

```
xinput disable 'SYNA8008:00 06CB:CE58 Touchpad'; sleep 2; xinput enable 'SYNA8008:00 06CB:CE58 Touchpad'
```

No chanes.

With `xinput test 'SYNA8008:00 06CB:CE58 Touchpad'` I can see, that there ARE signals received when I use the touchpad. Compared to pre-hibernate, there are A LOT less signals.

The "joystick" "mouse" always works. But **I** am not compatible with the knob ;)

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Your question isn't clear; you mention two different OSes, one on-topic here, one not - so please use SE Unix & Linux if you want to ask about both (both are on-topic there) or make your question meet this site's rules if you wish to stay here*  Please provide `uname -r` or kernel details.

Comment: Let's focus on Ubuntu 21.10 then, not that it matters. That seems to be an old issue - in https://askubuntu.com/questions/528293/is-there-a-way-to-restart-the-touchpad-driver#comment1965453_721045 somebody reported that also with Ubuntu 18.04. The post is from 2019. On my Ubuntu 21.10 installation, I'm using kernel 5.13.0-22.22.

Answer (score 1):

**HEUREKA!**

For whatever reason, *suspend* was set to "***S3 Linux***" in the *BIOS*. After changing it to "***Windows/Linux***", the touchpad seems to be working just fine after a wakeup.

Ah… What a relief ;) Now the device is so much more useful ;)

Comment: Watch battery usage on sleep, modern standby may be problematic on some hardware.

Comment: Heureka indeed! Thank you for this hint! It looks like switching the Sleep Mode from Linux to Windows actually is enough that my Linux Distro (Ubuntu based) works after hibernation