# Left mouse click stopped working after resuspend - Lenovo Thinkpad T14 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, suspend, mouse, touchpad

Oddly, this issue has appeared suddenly in a few occasions but now has been worsening over the last month:

**Every time my Lenovo Thinkpad T14 wakes up from suspend, my **left mouse click is unresponsive**- **both the trackpad/touchpad and the physical mouse button****. The only thing that works is to force via terminal into reboot.

The right click seems to still work normally. To me, it seems like an incompatibility of the Trackpad Driver-Ubuntu version or Kernel release. Any suggestions on what's worth upgrading?

****UPDATE**: I just found out that when I run the following commands (suggested in this post [Is there a way to "restart" the touchpad driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528293/is-there-a-way-to-restart-the-touchpad-driver))

```
sudo  modprobe -r psmouse
```

and then

```
sudo  modprobe psmouse
```

it creates the exact SAME FAULTY BEHAVIOR of my left mouse click, as the one I experience after re-suspend. It can then be fixed only with `xinput disable 11` and `xinput enable 11` (11=Touchpad id from xinput list)

Any clues?

**System Info**

```
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 
Kernel release 6.5.7-060507-generic
AMD® Ryzen 5 pro 4650u with radeon graphics × 12
```

Output from **xinput list-props 11**

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (169):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (171): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (307): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (308): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (309):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (310):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (311):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (312):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (313):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (314):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (315):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (316):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (317):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (318):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (319):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (320):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (321):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (322): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (323):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (324):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (325):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (326):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (327): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (328): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (329): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (330): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (292): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (293):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (294):    0, 0
    Device Node (295):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (296):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (331):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (332):   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of experience: most probably this is a hardware issue - either your mouse button is about to die or the touchpad is giving up.

I had exactly the same behavior on older Thinkpad HW. `modprobe psmouse` command helped intially, sometimes only reboot fixed it up until my touchpad gave up totally. Replacing the palmrest fixed everything.